# Updated Magento to 1.9.01 - All pages blank

Tags: php, error, ce-1.9.0.1

I have updated my site to v.1.9.0.1 and uploaded all the new version of my Joomlart theme to my hosting. All files uploaded successfully and now the frontend and backend of the site is just blank white pages.

A few people have suggested turning off compiler and flushing cache in the control panel or through shell, but I don't know how you do this? I can get access to phpmyadmin but don't know where to go from there.

I went to error logs on my hosting account and this came up:

```
[Sat May 24 19:30:25 2014] [error] [client 38.100.21.64] client denied by server configuration: /home/shop/public_html/errors/design.xml
[Sat May 24 19:30:25 2014] [error] [client 38.100.21.64] client denied by server configuration: /home/shop/public_html/errors/.htaccess
[Sat May 24 19:30:24 2014] [error] [client 38.100.21.64] client denied by server configuration: /home/shop/public_html/errors/default/report.phtml
[Sat May 24 19:30:24 2014] [error] [client 38.100.21.64] client denied by server configuration: /home/shop/public_html/errors/default/503.phtml
[Sat May 24 19:30:24 2014] [error] [client 38.100.21.64] client denied by server configuration: /home/shop/public_html/errors/default/404.phtml
[Sat May 24 19:30:24 2014] [error] [client 38.100.21.64] client denied by server configuration: /home/shop/public_html/errors/default/page.phtml
```

Any suggestions on a fix?

Comment: After looking at the errors you posted above, I feel like the installation was not a success. I would suggest you go into your file manager and clear out all folder/files in "var/cache", Then verify the permission levels on your folders/files. Folders should be at 755 and files should be at 644. If you are still experiencing the white screen of death, I would look in your Magento logs (var/log/system.log or exception.log) to see if you can find anymore errors. If you still can't find the issue, I would suggest installing a clean copy of 1.9 on your server and work your way backwards.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to remove files from /var/session as they are no more compatible with rest of the store.

Comment: Thanks I got it working! The main index.php had permissions not set at 644

Comment: Well, I am glad I figured out the issue in my first comment. Haha. I created an answer so this question can be closed, can you please mark it as the accepted solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to double check the permissions on your files/folders.

If you have SSH access, type these two lines.

```
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
```

Once that is done, delete everything in your "var/cache" folder and refresh.